# Python Dataframe: Calculate Number of Days Since Last Date In Previous Row and Place in New Column

Tags: python, loops, date, rows

UPDATE: Error --> "cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!"

After running the code below, I get the following output dataframe in Python:

```
df = df_EVENT5_18[['FLEET', 'SUBFLEET', 'AIRCRAFT', 'DTIN']]

df = df.sort_values(['FLEET', 'SUBFLEET', 'AIRCRAFT', 'DTIN'])

df.set_index(['FLEET', 'SUBFLEET', 'AIRCRAFT'], inplace=True)

# df = df.reset_index()
df['DTIN'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DTIN'])
```

[image]

But it errors out at the very last line of code:

```
df_EVENT5_19 = df.assign(output = df.groupby(['FLEET', 'SUBFLEET', 'AIRCRAFT']).DTIN.apply(lambda x: x.diff()))
```

This is the error: "cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!"

---

Below is a sample table that I am working with:

[image]

The columns UI_A, UI_B, and UI_C taken together form a unique identifier.

I want to calculate for each row and for each unique identifier the number of days it has been since the last date.  Essentially, if your unique identifier is the same then you need to reference the date one row above you.

This logic is a little difficult to explain in words so I'm including my desired output table below.  I want to create the column "Days Since Previous Date"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using pandas, you can use assign and then groupby

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'UI_A':['319','319','319','319','319','319','319','319','319','319'],
    'UI_B': ['131','131','131','131','131','131','131','131','131','131'],
    'UI_C': ['00319','00319','00319','04001','04001','04001','04002','04002','04002','04002'],
    'DATE' : ['2012-12-30','2013-02-05','2013-02-11','2009-10-25','2010-09-08','2011-01-16','2009-12-02','2010-09-27','2011-01-06','2011-02-09']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index(['UI_A','UI_B','UI_C'],inplace=True)
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df = df.assign(output=df.groupby(['UI_A','UI_B','UI_C']).DATE.apply(lambda x: x.diff()))
```

Out:

```
                      DATE   output
UI_A UI_B UI_C                     
319  131  00319 2012-12-30      NaT
          00319 2013-02-05  37 days
          00319 2013-02-11   6 days
          04001 2009-10-25      NaT
          04001 2010-09-08 318 days
          04001 2011-01-16 130 days
          04002 2009-12-02      NaT
          04002 2010-09-27 299 days
          04002 2011-01-06 101 days
          04002 2011-02-09  34 days
```

Comment: Great answer! +1  I think you could add `as_index=False` in your groupby to get back your original dataframe without indexing.

Comment: I'm getting the following error when I tried your code against my actual data: "cannot handle a non-unique multi-index"